# Can you encode two values in a single qubit state, say its phase and orientation?

Tags: quantum-state

I had an interesting talk with someone who said that we can use a single qubit to encode two different values. We encode the first value in its orientation (up/down) of particle/wave (electron, photon, etc.) and we encode the second value in the phase of that particle/wave. What do you think about that?

Comment: see https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/q/8645/55, https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/365453/58382, https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/382655/58382

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each qubit can be described as
$$
|\psi\rangle = \alpha|0\rangle+\mathrm{e}^{i\varphi}\beta|1\rangle,
$$
where $\alpha^2+\beta^2=1$. Both $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are real numbers. These values are so-called amplitudes and it holds that $P(|0\rangle) = \alpha^2$ and $P(|1\rangle) = \beta^2$. So, amplitudes describe probability that you find your qubit in either state after measurement (up or down in your question or $|0\rangle$ or $|1\rangle$ in example above). An angle $\varphi$ is the phase, the person you mentioned talked about. It is another purely quantum parameter of qubit (i.e. there is no analog in *classical world*). The existence of phase is one of reasons why quantum computer can be superior to classical one in some tasks.

**Appendix:**

You can also write the qubit as
$$
|\psi\rangle = \alpha|0\rangle+\beta|1\rangle,
$$
where $|\alpha|^2+|\beta|^2=1$. Both $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are complex numbers. These numbers are again called amplitudes and it holds that $P(|0\rangle) = |\alpha|^2$ and $P(|1\rangle) = |\beta|^2$. The phase is *hidden* in amplitudes in this case.

Both above mentioned forms can be transformed to each other (write complex numbers $\alpha$ and $\beta$ in expontential form).

Answer (score 4):

No. Even though you can encode information in both the amplitude and phase degrees of freedom independently, it is important that the two ``values'' be encoded in a way that they can be *successfully distinguished*. This nuance is captured by the so-called [Holevo's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holevo%27s_theorem) which essentially states that a qubit can contain *at most* one bit of information.

This is a fairly counterintuitive result since a single qubit state can take infinitely many values, corresponding to various choices of the amplitudes and phases. But since there are *only two* orthogonal states (for the pure state case), one can *retrieve* only a single bit of information from a qubit.

Answer (score 1):

What is "a single qubit state" in your question?

If it is really a single qubit in a unique unknown state and there are no other qubits in the same state (for example, prepared in the same way),
then in the [answer](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/a/12866/12280) it is already quite explained for this case.

If it is a single qubit in a quantum program (circuit) designed to be executed on a [NISQ](https://arxiv.org/abs/1801.00862v3) computer (or on its simulator),
then usually such a circuit is run several times (or shots) up to obtain stable results.
Thus, although one speaks of measuring a single qubit state, each shot a "new" state of the qubit is measured.
Accordingly, using multiple runs, you can get the orientation (e.g. up/down) in different proportions, which can "encode" various values.
Also two "encoded" values can be "decoded" from a single qubit, measuring the orientation (up/down) in half the cases, the phase in the other half.
And more than two values, if measuring this qubit in more then two various basises, for details see e.g. [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_tomography).