# What types of noise are there?

Tags: resource-request, noise

I know this does vary to some extent from implementation to implementation, but I'm looking for broad 'classes' of noise.

For example, I know a very common source of noise/error is the environment - things like thermal noise, and another common source is issues with gate fidelity. Is there any sort of comprehensive list of broad classes of error like this?

Any reference here would be greatly appreciated if the list is too long for a single answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What exactly is meant by "noise" in the following context?](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/69/what-exactly-is-meant-by-noise-in-the-following-context)

Comment: @SanchayanDutta I looked at that; it seems to describe different ways thermal noise specifically can affect a system, whereas I'm looking for a list of types of noise beyond thermal (like issues with gate fidelity).